# Using Quartz.Net embedded into a Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, quartz.net

I Am trying to use Quartz.Net so as to Schedule Jobs Within a Windows Service that I developped.

I included the following code on the *Onstart* Method, *scheduler* is a Class attribute 
`private readonly IScheduler scheduler;`

`logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (TelegestionService));

scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler();

var job = new JobDetail("job1", "group1", typeof (HelloJob));

var trigger = new SimpleTrigger("trigger1", "group1", runTime);

scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);`

This works fine for me. I got the Job running.

Now I'am trying to make the scheduler embedded remotely accessible, based en Example12 in the Quartz source Examples (the Console Server/Client works fine).

`var properties = new NameValueCollection();

properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "RemoteServer";

properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";

properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "5";

properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";

properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz";

properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.port"] = "555";

properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName"] = "QuartzScheduler";

properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType"] = "tcp";


scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties).GetScheduler();`

The service starts correctly and so does the scheduler but i cannot remotely schedule the Job using a Console/Winform Client (Connection refused).

I checked the LISTENING ports on my server using SysInternals TcpView and I cannot find the 555 port specified above.

Am suspecting an issue related to .Net Remoting but cannot figure out how to resolve this.
Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the Windows Firewall to make sure the executable can open that port?

Answer (score 0):

could use http://topshelf-project.com/ to host Scheduler which will provide hostFactory and using that could shelf host via HttpSelfHostServer, http is better as you could invoke job via controller.  sample code as below

hope this helps.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.SelfHost;
using Topshelf;
     class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HostFactory.Run(hostConfigurator =>
            {
                if (!Uri.TryCreate("http://localhost:8080", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out var hostname))
                {
                    throw new ConfigurationErrorsException($"Could not uri");
                }

                var serviceName = "my service";

                var hostConfiguration = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(hostname);
                hostConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", (object)new
                {
                    id = RouteParameter.Optional
                });

                var httpSelfHostServer = new HttpSelfHostServer(hostConfiguration);

                // Impl.Scheduler would be your implementation of scheduler
                hostConfigurator.Service<Impl.Scheduler>(s =>
                {
                    s.ConstructUsing(name => new Impl.Scheduler());
                    s.WhenStarted(tc =>
                    {
                        tc.Start();

                        httpSelfHostServer.OpenAsync().Wait();
                    });
                    s.WhenStopped(tc =>
                    {
                        tc.Stop();
                        //dispose scheduler implementation if using IOC container
                        httpSelfHostServer.CloseAsync().Wait();
                    });
                });
                hostConfigurator.RunAsLocalSystem();

                hostConfigurator.SetDescription(serviceName);
                hostConfigurator.SetDisplayName(serviceName);
                hostConfigurator.SetServiceName(serviceName);
            });
        }
    }
```